# Blender 2.73a crashes on start up

Tags: windows

I am using windows 7 64-bit, freshly installed. I installed Blender 2.73a but after installation, when I open blender it crashes (Blender has stopped working), but Blender 2.68 works perfectly fine.

A similar question has been asked before but the solutions haven't helped.

Comment: In your question please be explicit about which solutions you have tried, and what kind of graphics card you have.

Comment: Do any of the 2.7 series work on your machine?

Comment: im using an geforce 840m in my laptop i7 with 8 gb of ram windows 7 professional Edition, 

version that worked(windows 7):
2.68 and 2.70 only 

all the other version won't even start up even 2.73. it shows (blender has stopped working)

Note:I was using 2.73 before when i was in windows 8.1, last month i switched to windows 7 professional since then the most recent version i can used is only the 2.70a version.. Thank you everyone

Comment: i fix it myself. i followed a solution similar to my problem, by copying the python34 folder to (2.73/python) it worked, but, everytime i press shift z (rendered  view)it crashes. I guess i'll just have to use  2.70 until someone has fix this issues in later versions, by the way thanks everyone.

Answer (score 5):

If the problem is related to having a PYTHONPATH environment variable set, you can do the following so you don't have to modify your PYTHONPATH variable. I am running 2.75a and this fixed my problem.

1. Make a batch file somewhere like your desktop

   - To do so, create a blank .txt document and name it blender.bat (MAKE SURE THE EXTENSION IS .bat and not .txt)
2. Edit blender.bat and add the text below

   ```
   set PYTHONPATH=""
   cd C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\
   start blender.exe
   ```
3. Your blender path may be different, so make sure you find the correct path
4. run blender.bat

This will temporarily set the PYTHONPATH to "" (nothing) during your blender session but is restored after you close.

Comment: This suggestion resolved the issue for me on Windows 10 x64 with Blender 2.78a

Comment: Way to late but, it didn't helped. I'm getting "C++ Runtime Error"