# Blender crashes on startup

Tags: windows

When I launch Blender, it flashes the console on screen and then closes. I was able to see it failed to set to 48000Hz and saw a post that said I could open a console window from the blender folder and type `blender.exe -noaudio`. However now it says error:

```
EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION.
```

My specs are:

- CPU: intel i7-4790k
- GPU: gtx750 ti
- OS: Windows 7 enterprise 64-bit build 7600
- Motherboard: Gigabyte z97x-ud3h-bk
- RAM: 8GB

Comment: Try getting rid of the -noaudio bit. It should then show you the error on why it crashed (if there is one).

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27153/blender-2-73a-crashes-on-start-up

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2203/599